# Need to generate a windows authentication connection string

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, windows-authentication

I added an ADO.NET entity data model to my project but it did not add a connection string to this project (the project was not the active on startup project at creation, if that helps).  I am unsure how to generate a connection string for the project as it does not appear in any of the .config files in the project nor does it appear in the "Active Project at startup" .config files.

Comment: Were you using code first?

Comment: No, the database already exists.

Comment: So you have an EDMX model? In that case you set the connection string when updating the model from the database

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  Not sure why initially creating the new connection did that but when I tried to update it asked me to confirm a connection once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a model from the database you will be asked to provide a connection string. Sometimes this connection string can be lost (for instance when checking code into source control).

If you need to re-enter the connection string you can open your edmx file, and click the white area, then view the Properties window to see the connection string property. Alternatively you can set the connection string in the app.config file using the connection strings section.